# PHP - index.php and session

Tags: php

My question is about **index.php**.

(1) If I have a php file name called "index.php". When I access to the web page, it will    definitely go to the index.php page?

(2) login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$usrname = $_POST['username'];
$usrpassword = $_POST['password'];

if(!empty($usrname) && (!empty($usrpassword)))
{
    //db configuration
    $q = "select username from user where username = '".$usrname."' && userpwd = PASSWORD('$usrpassword')";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($r))
    {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);  
            session_regenerate_id();          
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            session_write_close();

            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
    }
}


<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Main Page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I close the browser on index.php, next time I must go to login.php again. But from my code, it doesn't go to the login.php page and remain at the index.php page. What mistake I had make? How should I solve it?

Comment: You have to create a deconnexion link or clear the cache of your browser

Comment: 1) It depends on how is setted your web space. Normally if you type your domain it will search a list of file.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you're currently vunerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You need to look at how the [sessions are configured](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php) on your system.  If using a cookie that doesn't expire when the browser is closed, the user will remain logged in.

Answer (score 2):

For store sessions id used cookies. When you close your browser then it should clear all cookies. But your browser don't make this.

Maybe you closed only window with this page, but not closed all browser application. In this case browser can store session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

create logout with session destroy.
create a logout link

```
<a href="logout.php"> Logout</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:login.html");
?>
```